# Automapper null collection becomes empty

Tags: c#, automapper

Why does automapper create empty instances of collections if they are null?
Here is my configuration

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AllowNullCollections = true;
        AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, DAL.Models.User>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Models.User, User>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Role, DAL.Models.Role>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Models.Role, Role>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Task, DAL.Models.Task>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Models.Task, Task>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<TaskReport, DAL.Models.TaskReport>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Models.TaskReport, TaskReport>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Project, DAL.Models.Project>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Models.Project, Project>();
    }
}
```

My models have the same properties:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TaskReport> TaskReports { get; set; } 
}
```

In my MVC project in Global.asax I'm just add my profile like this:

```
Mapper.AddProfile(new BL.MapperProfile());
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the mapping in the code?

Comment: I've modified my question. Hope it clarify it a bit

Comment: I was able to re-create the issue after your edits and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, my first answer was off the mark. I was able to re-create the issue and find out what's going on.

You are getting this error because of the static call to `Mapper.CreateMap` method. If you change your code to just call the non static `CreateMap` method you should be good.

```cs
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AllowNullCollections = true;
        AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

        // calling non-static CreateMap
        CreateMap<User, DAL.Models.User>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Models.User, User>();
        CreateMap<Role, DAL.Models.Role>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Models.Role, Role>();
        CreateMap<Task, DAL.Models.Task>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Models.Task, Task>();
        CreateMap<TaskReport, DAL.Models.TaskReport>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Models.TaskReport, TaskReport>();
        CreateMap<Project, DAL.Models.Project>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Models.Project, Project>();
    }
}
```